# mySQL collation latin + chinese

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a database which uses roman text and chinese. In the tables I would like to be able to sort case sensitively eg
CAT
Cat
DOG
Dog
with Chinese coming after these.

utf8_general_ci allows me to combine the English and the Chinese but won't allow CAT and Cat as separate, indexable items.
latin1_general_cs won't allow the Chinese.

Does anyone know a way round this? Thanks

Comment: Can you use utf8_bin?

Comment: That seems to work fine. Thanks Strawberry